# Properties of pseudorandom ternary sequences

Tags: reference-request, random, lfsr

For pseudo-random binary sequences, we know there are various [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_binary_sequence): Autocorrelation, balance, Fibonacci vs Galois modes. These are all well-known.

However, for pseudo-random ternary sequences, I have been unable to find authoritative references. Where can I find a detailed exposition about PRTS sequences?

Comment: What do _you_ understand by ternary sequence? There are at least two different versions: sequences from an alphabet that is $\{-1, 0, +1\}$ and sequences from an alphabet that is $\{1, \omega, \omega^2\}$ where $\omega = \exp(j2\pi/3)$ is a complex cube root of unity, and the two have different properties.

Comment: @DilipSarwate:  {-1, 0, +1}.